# How to calculate "badness" for ragged right margins?

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs, badness

In TeXbook (p.30) it is said:

> When `\raggedright` has been specified, badness reflects the amount of space at the right margin, instead of the spacing between words.

That is, in ragged-right case, badness is difference between required and actual width (not `100*r^3`). In the following example badness must be stretchability of rightskip (i.e., `2em`), so considering that `1em` is `10pt`, badness must be `20`, but `badness 100` is output. Why?

```
\hbadness=-1 % to report the badness
\raggedright % \rightskip 0pt plus2em \spaceskip.3333em
\def\text{The badness of this line is 1000.}
\setbox0=\hbox{\text}
\hsize=\wd0 \advance\hsize by 2em \noindent\text\break
\bye
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment just means that the only stretch glue is at the right not between words, not that a different calculation is being used, badness 100 means stretched by cube root of 100/100 which is a factor of 1, so basically you are just seeing the effects of rounding error. In other words, badness is `(20/20)^3*100`.